# how to let activity work in background after click back button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using Activity to get data permanently from vehicule using BLE `BluetoothLeService` like (vehicule speed, temperature, etc) and inject it to `Sqlite DataBase` in real time,
until there it works perfectly.

My problem is that when i press key back to return to my principle activity i want to keep the scanning.

So i tried to override `onKeyDown` like the following but when i click keyBack the scanning still working but it puts all the application `onBackground` not only the activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch(keyCode)
    {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I tried also to put `moveTaskToBack(true)` inside `onStop` and when i click keyBack the scanning getting stoped.

i've searched a lot and tried a several solutions but still not working. Any suggestions or other ideas i'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using Activity. Use [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for long operations. "A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use" is from documentation [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to created a background service which will keep scanning in the background. When ever your Activity need data form service you can ask the service through a BroadcastReceiver .